# Area under parabola using geometry

Tags: geometry, definite-integrals, conic-sections, area

[image]

We have to find the area of the pink region. As we all know this can be evaluated using limiting its Riemann sum, of which its a standard example. However I want to know if this can be done without using calculus, with directly using geometry. I think it would be very interesting challenge, but I am not able to think of a way out.

Comment: IIRC, Archimedes thought of a way to do it.

Comment: @DavidMitra I think he used limits without using it formally. Not sure though.

Comment: But, it amounts to taking the limit of certain sums. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Quadrature_of_the_Parabola).

Comment: One might imagine a Cavallieri's Principle argument, which would arguably be "without calculus". I can't, however, think of an obvious one :( BTW, I think that @Daniel Rust meant to say "that the area was $1/3$" rather than $2$. Proving the area was $2$ would be *really* impressive. :)

Comment: @John haha thanks, I should probably go back to topology where numbers don't have as much meaning :P.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends a little bit what you mean by geometry.  If you can see "geometrically" that stretching the function horizontally by a factor of $2$ should double the value of the integral, and if you can see "geometrically" that the integral of a sum of two functions should be the sum of the integrals, then there is such a proof, and I spell it out here:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114738/integrating-powers-without-much-calculus/114843#114843

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 2):

Using a similar transformation used by Archimedes for sphere and cylinder, show equivalence of slice of the curve at point $x$ to the area of a pyramid slice.  The total area will be equal to the volume of the pyramid of unit base and height.  This is however equivalent to calculus (under disguise.)