# Find the area of $y = x^2$ without calculus

Tags: linear-algebra, integration

Is it possible to find the area bounded by $x=0, y=1, y=x^2$ without using calculus? I know the answer is $\frac{2}{3}$, easily found with integration.

Comment: Actually, it is $1/3$.

Comment: I don't think so. If by "Calculus" you mean "a limiting technique". Even Archimedes used a limiting technique.

Comment: I seem to recall that this was asked a few days ago...

Comment: What about using Riemann Sums? I believe that will work to give you an approximate.

Comment: @Ron are you sure?

Comment: There is a beautiful thread on MathOverflow that handles the general function $f(x)=x^p$. Let me find it for you. Edit: See David Mitra's comment.

Comment: [Here is the post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/653412/area-under-parabola-using-geometry).

Comment: I think you mistyped.  If the bounds are $y=0$, then $2/3$ is it.

Comment: @Ron If the bound is $y=0$ there's infinite area

Comment: @David Very interesting post, thank you for showing me it

Comment: No, I meant $y=0$ instead of $x=0$.

Comment: How would you defined area in this case?

Comment: See *Archimedes'* [Quadrature of the Parabola](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Quadrature_of_the_Parabola).

Comment: @RonGordon, if we refer to the OP's area of integration, then the area is $$\int\limits_0^1\left(1-x^2\right)dx=\frac23$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is stated in the comments, even Archimedes used a raw form of a limiting technique to find the answer to your problem; but then, after all, "Calculus" refers often to theories after Leibnitz's and Newton's works only.

Therefore: Archimedes demonstrated that the area enclosed between a parabola and a  straight line crossing it can be calculated as the $2/3$ of the area of a specific rectangle. This rectangle is built from the segment that the parabola itself cuts out of the straight line, a parallel to that line tangent to the parabola, and two segments, orthogonal to the previous lines, drawn from the intersection points between the parabola and the first line.

Much to our pleasure the area you ask for is exactly half of the one enclosed between $y=x^2$ and $y=1$. The rectangle has vertices $(1,0)(1,1)(0,1)(-1,1)$, and its area is $2.$
$$
\mathcal{A} = 2 \cdot \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2}  = \frac{2}{3}
$$